# How to run netstat -b 5?

Tags: windows-7, permissions

I have Win 7 on my home computer.

When I type "netstat -b 5" it says "The requested operation requires elevation."

How do I elevate myself?  I am the only person on the computer.

Answer (score 3):

> **How do I elevate myself?**

Instead of opening a command prompt window in the normal way, right-click the option and choose "run as administrator"

<sub>or stand on a chair</sub>